# How to recover emails from a closed server

Tags: email, web-crawler, webarchive

I have an old email account on Altern.org. Unfortunately, the server had been closed and I didn't succeed to contact the moderator to retrieve my emails.
Is there any archive server (as [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org)) to recover my old emails.

Comment: That would be somewhat disturbing from a security viewpoint. :\

Comment: Not just distributing from the security point. Mail hostings always have law aspects. Usually data should be erased after passing some time. You can contact the admin of the server or the company, maybe giving your personal identification you can retrieve your data just if exists some backup. But your data after sometime should be erased, ofc, it depends of the place: https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/rules-business-and-organisations/principles-gdpr/how-long-can-data-be-kept-and-it-necessary-update-it_en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the email service has ended and you have no way to contact the company that ran it, then you will have no ability to access your old email.  Email is not like public websites, which are available to everyone - including archival robots.  No one would want their mail crawled and posted online for other people to see.  Unfortunately, unless you can get ahold of the administrators of the email server/company, the email is gone.

Comment: I am afraid, the email is gone!

Comment: @user56980 That is unfortunate.  As the saying goes, if its important make a backup!